# Return/Enter key does nothing in Matlab's "Find & Replace" GUI

Tags: java, matlab

In the Matlab editor, I type command-F pulling up the "Find & Replace" GUI, then type a string in the "Find what:" field. The "Find Next" button is now highlighted, but when I hit the return key, nothing happens. I have to manually click the "Find Next" button with the mouse each time. It's a small issue but it's driving me nuts, and interrupts my coding flow.

I suspect it might have to do with the version of java running, which I messed around with because retina displays had a known issue with image/text quality in matlab and using this version of java was the workaround.

Running Matlab on 2013 Macbook Pro w/ Retina, OS X Version 10.9.5
Matlab version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Java version: Java 1.8.0_40-b27 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Any ideas how to fix the return key issue without reverting to fuzzy text in matlab?

Comment: This seems like a question best answered by MathWorks. It also has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: How long have you been using these versions of Java/Matlab? Maybe the 2014b or 2015a upgrades have fixed the issues?

Comment: @excaza, Thanks, I'll try asking there too, but in my experience responding to student licensees is not high on MathWorks' priority list.

Comment: @Delyle, I've been using this combo of Matlab and Java for about 6 months, after I switched from a non-retina Macbook to my current one.  I'm hoping to avoid updating the version of Matlab until I'm done with my dissertation analyses.